# create a package with only a specification

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The code listed below creates a package with only a specification and holds tax rates. I need to be able to display those rates in an anonymous block to display the value of each packaged variable. Is this possible somehow or do I need to put more logic in my specification? Any help would be appreciated.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE 
 TAXRATE_PKG IS

 PROCEDURE state_tax_pf(
            p_state IN VARCHAR2,
            pv_tax_nc IN NUMBER := 0.35, 
            pv_tax_tx IN NUMBER := 0.05, 
            pv_tax_tn IN NUMBER := 0.02) ;

END TAXRATE_PKG;
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want a package that just has a few constants rather than a procedure?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE 
 TAXRATE_PKG 
IS

 g_tax_rate_nc constant NUMBER := 0.35;
 g_tax_rate_tx constant number := 0.05;
 g_tax_rate_tn constant number := 0.02;

END TAXRATE_PKG;
```

It seems a bit odd to want to have constants for different state tax rates however.  It seems more likely that you'd want that to be stored in a table and to create a function that takes a state and returns the rate stored in that table.

```
CREATE TABLE state_tax_rate (
  state_code varchar2(2) primary key,
  tax_rate   number(3,2)
);

insert into state_tax_rate( state_code, tax_rate )
  values( 'NC', 0.35 );
insert into state_tax_rate( state_code, tax_rate )
  values( 'TX', 0.05 );
insert into state_tax_rate( state_code, tax_rate )
  values( 'TN', 0.02 );

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE taxrate_pkg
IS
  FUNCTION get_rate( p_state IN state_tax_rate.state_code%type )
    RETURN state_tax_rate.tax_rate%type;
END taxrate_pkg;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY taxrate_pkg
AS
  FUNCTION get_rate( p_state IN state_tax_rate.state_code%type )
    RETURN state_tax_rate.tax_rate%type
  IS
    l_tax_rate state_tax_rate.tax_rate%type;
  BEGIN
    SELECT tax_rate
      INTO l_tax_rate
      FROM state_tax_rate
     WHERE state_code = p_state;

    RETURN l_tax_rate;
  END get_rate;
END taxrate_pkg;
```

Comment: @user3508766 - You'd need to implement the function in the package body. You declare it in the specification.

Comment: something like this?                                                                                                                           CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE 
 TAXRATE_PKG IS FUNCTION

  state_tax_pf(
            p_state IN VARCHAR2,
            pv_tax_nc IN NUMBER, 
            pv_tax_tx IN NUMBER, 
            pv_tax_tn IN NUMBER)
            
        BEGIN 
       IF p_state = 'NC' THEN 
           pv_tax_nc := 0.35; 
       ELSIF p_state = 'TX' THEN 
           Pv_tax_tx := 0.05; 
       ELSIF p_state = 'TN' THEN 
           pv_tax_tn := 0.02; 
       END IF; 

END TAXRATE_PKG;

Comment: @user3508766 - Why do you want state parameters to the function.  I would expect the function to take a single parameter, the state, and return a numeric value, the tax rate.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE 
 TAXRATE_PKG IS FUNCTION

  state_tax_pf(
            p_state IN VARCHAR2,
            pv_tax_nc OUT NUMBER, 
            pv_tax_tx OUT NUMBER, 
            pv_tax_tn OUT NUMBER)
            
            RETURN lv_state;
            
        BEGIN 
       IF p_state = 'NC' THEN 
           pv_tax_nc := 0.35; 
       ELSIF p_state = 'TX' THEN 
           Pv_tax_tx := 0.05; 
       ELSIF p_state = 'TN' THEN 
           pv_tax_tn := 0.02; 
       END IF; 

END TAXRATE_PKG;

Comment: @user3508766 - I updated my answer with what I would expect you really want.

Comment: That is great and it makes sense but I am to create a package with only a specification and holds tax rates mentioned and display them in anonymous block

Comment: @user3508766 - If this is a homework assignment with artificial constraints, I expect that you'd use the specification I posted initially that just declares some package global variables.

Comment: Thanks I will use that, how would I display it in the anonymous block with DBMS?